# Data not display in the sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a SQlite database table in my android project, I can insert row and retrieve the values from that table, but if I try to load the database table from Sqlite software it doesn't display my table, please give a solution thank you.

What I have tried:

```
//creating Database
private static final String TABLE_BUYMAGISSUE= "buymagazine";//buy issues table
private static final String MAGCAT_ID= "magid";
private static final String MAGSELECTBOOK_ID= "issueid";
private static final String MAGBUY_ID= "androidissuebuyid";
private static final String MAGBUYIMG_URL= "coverimage_path";
private static final String MAGBUY_TITLE= "title";
private static final String MAGBUYPDF_URL= "uploadfile_path";

String CREATE_BUYMAGTABLE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BUYMAGISSUE + "("+ KEY_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + MAGCAT_ID + " TEXT," + MAGSELECTBOOK_ID + " TEXT," + MAGBUY_ID + " TEXT," + MAGBUYIMG_URL + " TEXT," + MAGBUY_TITLE + " TEXT," +MAGBUYPDF_URL +" TEXT" + ")";
  db.execSQL(CREATE_BUYMAGTABLE);

  //Inserting  Values
  dbs.insertBuyedMagIssueDetails(strMagBookId, select_bookID, buyIssue_ID, strBuyImg, strBuyTitle, strBuyPDF);

  //DBclass
  public  void insertBuyedMagIssueDetails(String strMagBookId,String select_bookID,String strBuyID,String strBuyImg,String strBuyTitle,String strBuyPDF) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //bookname=bookname.trim();
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MAGCAT_ID, strMagBookId);
        values.put(MAGSELECTBOOK_ID, select_bookID);
        values.put(MAGBUY_ID, strBuyID);
        values.put(MAGBUYIMG_URL, strBuyImg);
        values.put(MAGBUY_TITLE, strBuyTitle);
        values.put(MAGBUYPDF_URL, strBuyPDF);

        db.insert(TABLE_BUYMAGISSUE, null, values);

        Log.d("inserted success",TABLE_BUYMAGISSUE);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 // Retrieving values
 ArrayList<List<String>> arrbookcatgory = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
 arrbookcatgory = dbs.getBuyMagIssueName("buymagazine");

                String[] arrCatId = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];
                String[] arrSelectBook = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];
                String[] arrBuyId = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];
                String[] arrBuyImage = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];
                String[] arrBuyTitle = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];
                String[] arrBuyPdf = new String[arrbookcatgory.size()];

                int length = arrbookcatgory.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    arrCatId[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(0);
                    arrSelectBook[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(1);
                    arrBuyId[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(2);
                    arrBuyImage[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(3);
                    arrBuyTitle[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(4);
                    arrBuyPdf[i] = arrbookcatgory.get(i).get(5);
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        //DB class
           public ArrayList<List<String>> getBuyMagIssueName(String tableName)
{
    Cursor c = null;
    ArrayList<List<String>> Category=new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        SQLiteDatabase db =myDataBase;// getReadableDatabase();
        //String query="SELECT * FROM  subcategory   where catid=?" ,   new String [] {catId};
        //String query="SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE catid ="+ catId+"";
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" ",null);
        if (c.getCount()>0)
        {
            if(c.moveToFirst()) // rent
            {
                do
                {
                    ArrayList<String> listRent = new ArrayList<String>() ;
                    String Catid=c.getString(0);
                    String selectIssueid=c.getString(1);
                    String buyId=c.getString(2);
                    String buyImage=c.getString(3);
                    String buyTitle=c.getString(4);
                    String buyPdf=c.getString(5);


                    listRent.add(Catid);
                    listRent.add(selectIssueid);
                    listRent.add(buyId);
                    listRent.add(buyImage);
                    listRent.add(buyTitle);
                    listRent.add(buyPdf);

                    Category.add(listRent);
                }
                while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return Category;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if (c!=null)
            c.close();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: how you take your table ?

Comment: tell me clearly @Sree

Comment: From where you are taking the table where data is not present ?

Comment: inserting and retreriving not an issue,my database not display in sqlite

Comment: where you are testing you application. In device or emulator ?

Comment: how you get your database??

Comment: So may be you are taking from a wrong path or database is getting clear when you exit your app

Comment: i am detailedly mentioned how i create data base table and inserting reteriving values@NilsPatel

Comment: totally i am creating 10 tables except this one table remaing tables are shown in the sqlite@Sree

Comment: are you getting value from this table tooo ha? uninstall the app and install , then try to get your DB

Comment: @Androiddeveloper i mean how you get .db file from emulator??

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in a transaction (and COMMIT it) if you want the values to be saved on completion.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.beginTransaction()
```

...insert, update, delete, etc

```
if (ok) {
db.setTransactionSucessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

sorry 'bout formatting, been awhile since i've answered anything.